# nVidia drivers for Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

Right now Bumblebee is working with nvidia-331.113 driver, but in Software&Drivers is available nvidia-340. Should I update? I have some problems with this driver, while playing my fps instantly drops down to 10-15fps. I ask because I don't want to have a black screen after update. Thanks!